# FLUTTER 3 and latest VS Code: "stful" and "stless" does not create the widgets

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have not used Flutter for a few months so when I wanted to create a new project I upgraded to Flutter 3 and VS Code to

Version: 1.67.2 (user setup)
Commit: c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5
Date: 2022-05-17T18:15:52.058Z
Electron: 17.4.1
Chromium: 98.0.4758.141
Node.js: 16.13.0
V8: 9.8.177.13-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043

My problem is "stful" and "stless" does not create the widgets.

Flutter Doctor. No issues found.

I have tried to Google it with no responce. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the plugin Flutter Widget Snippets installed? It supports these. Also, have you updated the Flutter plugin?

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled both of them but it still does not work.

Comment: I installed Awesome Flutter Snippets but that did not work either. Then I installed a 6 month old version of VS Code still no luck.

Comment: Sorry I am out of ideas. Can you completely reinstall VS Code? Maybe that will help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your file name ends with ".dart"